# IUPAC Nomenclature of organic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Can the prefixes like iso,neo be used in the IUPAC nomenclature of organic compounds and can all the common names of aromatic compounds be used in their IUPAC name?

Comment: Related: [Can we use prefixes like iso, neo, etc in IUPAC nomenclature of organic compounds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/53256/7951)

Answer (score -1):

1. Prefixes -  I think the prefixes neo, iso etc. are used only in common names. There's a different system in IUPAC for naming things having a branched chain.
2. Aromatic Compounds - The only aromatic compound that I know of having same common and IUPAC name is benzene.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but it might be related to *I think...* The question is clear and the answer straightforward, possibly from the red book of IUPAC...; But your answer  fits pretty well as a comment!